# WP8.1 Dynamically Created Image is missing

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8, .net-4.5, dispatcher

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8.1 application using a Hub control to dynamically display categories (as HubSections) and images (contained within a StackPanel in each HubSection).

The process runs in two stages. The first part downloads XML from an API and parses it to store the Categories and their Images into a Dictionary. The code then loops through the category list and calls the Dispatcher to add the HubSections to the Hub with placeholder images to begin with. All of this runs in a background Task.

```
Private Async Sub GetXML()
    For Each Category As String In MessageMgr.CategoryList.Keys

            Await Hub.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                                   Sub()
                                                       AddHubSection(Category, MessageMgr.CategoryList(Category), Hub)
                                                       RaiseEvent HubSectionAdded(Category, MessageMgr, Hub)

                                                   End Sub)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub AddHubSection(Category As String, MessageList As List(Of MessageManager.Message), Hub As Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Hub)
    Dim HubSection As New Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.HubSection

    Dim TemplateString As String = "<DataTemplate>"...."</DataTemplate>"

    HubSection.Header = Category
    HubSection.ContentTemplate = XamlReader.Load(TemplateString)
    Hub.Sections.Add(HubSection)
End Sub
```

The Sub that is executed by the Dispatcher than raises an event so that I know the code has completed. This event then fires off another background Task to download all of the imagery and update the image placeholders. I use a recursively looping function (FindChildControl) to search for the image control within the Hub and then update it's source.

```
Private Sub OnHubSectionAdded(ByVal Category As String, ByVal MessageMgr As MessageManager, ByVal Hub As Hub)
    For Each Banner In MessageMgr.CategoryList(Category)
        Task.Run(Sub() GetImage(Banner, Hub))

    Next
End Sub

Private Async Sub GetImage(Banner As MessageManager.Message, Hub As Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Hub)
    Dim Declarations.....

    ''' Download image code goes here '''

            Await Hub.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                          Sub()
                                              imgBanner = FindChildControl(Of Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image)(Hub, "img" & Banner.BannerID)

                                              If imgBanner IsNot Nothing Then
                                                  myBitmapImage = New BitmapImage
                                                  myBitmapImage.SetSource(RAS)
                                                  imgBanner.Source = myBitmapImage
                                              End If
                                          End Sub)

End Sub
```

The problem I'm facing is that the FindChildControl function doesn't always return the Image control straight away. What I've done for now is wrap a While around it with a short Task.Delay and a timeout after 10 seconds to drop out. The control always becomes available within 1 second.

My question, though, is why is the Image not found in the Hub when I make an immediate pass through? I don't particularly want to have to resort to a While in the code to wait for it to become available.